# Trying to match stock tickers to adjusted.price

Tags: r

I have the script below which pulls in historical stock prices just fine, but I can't seem to get a list of tickers, by date, with adjusted prices.  I'm getting 25 stocks, and headers that look like this: $df.tickers, price.open, price.high, price.low, price.close, volume price.adjusted

One thing that I can't figure out is that when I type 'out' I get the data set, but when I type dim(out) I get a null.  That's doesn't make any sense.  Anyway, I'm trying to run the code from the link below.

http://programmingforfinance.com/2017/10/portfolio-optimization-with-r/

Here is the code that I'm working with.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(sqldf)
library(dplyr)

# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 360
last.date <- Sys.Date()

# set tickers
tickers <- c('MMM','ABT','ABBV','ABMD',
'ACN','ATVI','AYI','ADBE','AMD','AAP',
'AES','AET','AMG','AFL','A','APD','AKAM',
'ALK','ALB','ARE','ALXN','ALGN','ALLE','AGN','ADS')

out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date, 
                         cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                  'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()

# dim(out$df.tickers)
# 6175 10


# After downloading the data, we can check the success of the process for each ticker. 
# Notice that the last ticker does not exist in yahoo finance or google and therefore 
# results in an error. All information regarding the download process is provided in the dataframe df.control:

# print(out$df.control)
price_adjusted <- as.data.frame(out)
price_final <- subset(price_adjusted, select = c(df.control.ticker, df.tickers.price.adjusted, df.tickers.ref.date))
#    df_final <- subset(price_final, df.control.ticker == 'MMM', select = c("df.control.ticker","df.tickers.price.adjusted","df.tickers.ref.date"))
```

I believe the Google API was turned off last year, and as such, you can't get historical stock prices from Google anymore.  Any thoughts on how to make this work?  Thanks!

Comment: What is the class of out ? `dim` will give the dimensions of a dataframe or matrix, etc. but not a list for example. Can you be more specific about which lined failed for you?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're onto something here.  I think I need to convert a list to a data frame.  I did this: price_adjusted <- as.data.frame(out)  That seems to be pretty close.  25 stocks * 247 days = 6175 and that's the number of rows I'm getting.  Now, I think I should be able to select 2 columns, as such:  
library(sqldf)
df1 <- sqldf("select df.control.ticker, df.tickers.price.adjusted from price_adjusted")

However, that gives me the following error: Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near ".": syntax error

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the sqldf library to run the tutorial. The Google finance option is defunct, so can you tell us how you obtained your data? Did you use yahoo or another source? You can use `dput` to output some sample data to show us.

Comment: Whoops!  I thought I posted the code.  Too tired now.  Ok, I just updated my original post with the code that I am testing.  Basically, i'm trying to run the script from the URL I posted.  I'm trying to add in a different source for daily historical adjusted prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is using data in the 'xts' time series format. To convert your data as such,

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(tidyr)
library(quantmod)

# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 360
last.date <- Sys.Date()

# set tickers
tickers <- c('MMM','ABT','ABBV','ABMD',
             'ACN','ATVI','AYI','ADBE','AMD','AAP',
             'AES','AET','AMG','AFL','A','APD','AKAM',
             'ALK','ALB','ARE','ALXN','ALGN','ALLE','AGN','ADS')

out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                       first.date = first.date,
                       last.date = last.date, 
                       cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                'BGS_Cache') ) 
out<-out$df.tickers
out<-out[,c("ref.date","ticker", "price.adjusted")]
q <- spread(out, ticker, price.adjusted)
portfolioPrices <- xts(q[,-1], order.by=q[,1])
```

Comment: That works!  Thanks a lot!! I just had to add 1 line to de-dupe records.  Not sure why dupes are coming in, but the prior day was repeating, for some reason.  this fixed it: deduped_data <- unique( out[ , 1:3 ] )